# How to add a completion block to an IOS call

Tags: ios7

I need to wait for savePhototoImage to complete before moving on in my processing.  I assume a completion block is the way to do this.

I have seen a few completion blocks in IOS code, but do not know much about how they are made up.

Can a completion block be added to any function and if so, what would be the correct syntax to add one to this function?

```
BOOL saved = [Network savePhotoImage:img :self.description :@"Photo"];
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewController.m

```
  [Network savePhotoImage:img  :self.description :@"Photo" withCallback:^(BOOL success)
    {
        NSLog(@"executing callback");
         if (success)
         {
             NSLog(@"got callback success");
         }
         else
         {
            NSLog(@"got callback failure");
         }

     }];
```

Network.m

```
+ (void)savePhotoImage:(UIImage*)PhotoImage :(NSString*)description :(NSString*)imageName withCallback:(ASCompletionBlock)callback
{
    add workdone code here...
    if (workdone)
       callback(YES);
    } else {
        callback(NO);
    }
}
```

Network.h

```
typedef void (^ASCompletionBlock)(BOOL success);

+ (void)savePhotoImage:(UIImage*)PhotoImage :(NSString*)description : (NSString*)imageName withCallback:(ASCompletionBlock)callback;
```